# Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException in run method

Tags: java, multithreading

I can't find the error, say something about `run()`, but looks like right.

```
package Animation;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import Point.Point;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Animation extends TimerTask{
  private int radius;     
  private int segments;   
  private int repetitions;
  private int x_0, y_0;
  private ArrayList<Point> point_list;

    //variáveis panit
    //-------------------------------------------------- 
  Point pi = new Point();
  Point pf = new Point();
  private double size; 
  private double jump_delta;
  private double remainder;
  private double jump_alfa;    
  private int jump;

    //TODO: instanciar variáveis como privadas
  Rectangle2D.Double quad;

  Shape s;

  double[] matrizInicial;
  double[] matrizFinal;   

  AffineTransform inicialTranformation;
  AffineTransform tracking ;

  AffineTransform transfIntermed;
  Flag turn;
  Shape aux; 

    //The window in which everything is shown.
  private BufferedImageDrawer buffid;

    //The background image
  private BufferedImage bg;

    //calculateBpasenham
    //----------------------------------------------------------
  AffineTransform tr;
  AffineTransform origem;
  AffineTransform at;


  public Animation(BufferedImageDrawer bid, BufferedImage backGround,
    int height,int delay,  int r, int s, int n, int x, int y ) {

    this.radius      = r;
    this.segments    = s;
    this.repetitions = n;
    this.x_0         = x;  
    this.y_0         = y;  

    point_list = calculateBrasenham();


    //addWindowListener(new MyFinishWindow());

  }

  private ArrayList<Point> calculateBrasenham() {

    ArrayList<Point> left_half  = new ArrayList<Point>(); 
    ArrayList<Point> rigth_half = new ArrayList<Point>();

    int x = 0;
    int y = radius;
    int decision_var = 1 - radius;

    rigth_half.add( new Point(x , y  ) );

    while ( y > x ) {

      x++;

      if (decision_var < 0) {
        decision_var += 2 * x + 3;
      } else {

        decision_var += 2 * ( x - y ) + 5;
        y--;
      }

      rigth_half.add( new Point(x , y ) );      
    }

    for (Point tmp : rigth_half ) {
     left_half.add( 0,  new Point( tmp.get_y() , tmp.get_x() ));
   }

   ArrayList<Point> final_list = new ArrayList<Point>();

   for (Point tmp : left_half) {
    final_list.add(0, new Point( -tmp.get_x(), tmp.get_y()) );
  }

  int size = rigth_half.size() - 1;

  for (int i = size; i > 0; i-- ) {
    final_list.add( new Point( -rigth_half.get(i).get_x() , rigth_half.get(i).get_y() ) );
  }

  rigth_half.addAll(left_half);

  final_list.addAll(rigth_half);


  for (int i = 0; i < final_list.size(); i++ ) {

    Point tmp = final_list.get(i);
    final_list.get(i).set_x(tmp.get_x() + radius);
    final_list.get(i).set_y(tmp.get_y() );
  }


  return final_list;

}

private void calculateTransformations(Point pf, Flag turn, AffineTransform t) {

  tr = new AffineTransform();

  tr.setToTranslation(pf.get_x(), pf.get_y());      

  if ( turn.get_value() == true ) {

    origem = new AffineTransform();
    origem.setToTranslation(x_0,y_0);

    at = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(-Math.PI / 4,pf.get_x() ,pf.get_y() );

    t.concatenate(origem);
    t.concatenate(at);
    t.concatenate(tr);
    t.scale(1.5,1.5);

    turn.set_value(false); 

  } else {
    origem = new AffineTransform();
    origem.setToTranslation(x_0,y_0);

    at = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(0,pf.get_x() ,pf.get_y() );
    t.concatenate(origem);
    t.concatenate(at);
    t.concatenate(tr);

    turn.set_value(true);
  }
}

private void calculateInterpolationPoints(Point pf, int jump, int i ,int r ) {

  int size = point_list.size() - 1;

  if ( (i * jump  + jump) > size ) {
    pf.set_x(point_list.get(size).get_x() + r);
    pf.set_y(point_list.get(size).get_y());

  } else {
    pf.set_x(point_list.get((i * jump ) + jump ).get_x() + r);
    pf.set_y(point_list.get((i * jump ) + jump ).get_y()); 
  }
}

public void run() {

  buffid.g2dbi.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

  size = (double)point_list.size();

  jump_delta = size / segments;

  remainder = size % segments;
  jump_alfa = (int)(remainder/jump_delta);

  jump = (int) jump_delta;

  segments = segments + (int)jump_alfa;

  pi.set_x(point_list.get(0).get_x());
  pi.set_y(point_list.get(0).get_y());

  quad = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 10 , 10);

  AffineTransform normalizer = new AffineTransform();
  normalizer.setToScale(1, -1);

  AffineTransform translate = new AffineTransform();
  translate.setToTranslation(0, y_0 + radius + 100);
  normalizer.preConcatenate(translate);

  buffid.g2dbi.transform(normalizer);

  matrizInicial = new double[6];
  matrizFinal   = new double[6];

  inicialTranformation = new AffineTransform();

  tracking = new AffineTransform();

  inicialTranformation.setToTranslation(x_0 + pi.get_x(), y_0 + pi.get_y());
  inicialTranformation.getMatrix(matrizInicial); 

  turn = new Flag(true);

  buffid.g2dbi.setPaint(Color.white);
  buffid.g2dbi.fill(new Rectangle(0,0,radius * 2 * repetitions + 100 + x_0 + radius,radius + y_0 + 100));

  for ( int r = 0; r < repetitions; r++ ) {

    int shift = r * radius * 2;

    for (int j = 0; j < segments; j++) {

      calculateInterpolationPoints(pf, jump, j, shift);

      calculateTransformations( pf, turn, tracking);

      tracking.getMatrix(matrizFinal);

      aux = null;

      for (double step = 0; step < 35; step++ ) {

        transfIntermed = new AffineTransform( interpola( matrizInicial, matrizFinal, step/35) );
        s = transfIntermed.createTransformedShape(quad);

          // limpaJanela(buffid.g2dbi, aux);
          // buffid.g2dbi.setPaint(Color.black);          
          // buffid.g2dbi.draw(s);
          // congela(10);
        aux = s;
      }

      tracking.setToIdentity();

      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) matrizInicial[i] = matrizFinal[i];        
    }
}
}

public double[] interpola(double[] inicial,double[] terminal, double alfa) {
  double[] intermed = new double[inicial.length];

  for (int i=0; i<intermed.length; i++)
  {
    intermed[i] = (1-alfa)*inicial[i] + alfa*terminal[i];
  }

  return(intermed);
}
}
```

the error:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Animation.Animation.run(Animation.java:181)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Comment: Don't post a link to your code. Instead post pertinent code **here** with your question. I've done this for you now, but in the future, please do this yourself for all of us and for all future visitors to this site.

Comment: sorrry, I think it is big to post here, and thanks.

Comment: You still haven't shown us which line is 181. Please fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either buffid or buffid.g2dbi is not initialized.